# Adding Windows 7 to Fedora 17 Grub Boot Loader

Tags: windows, fedora, multi-boot

I'm trying to set up a dual-boot situation with my Windows 7 and Fedora 17 partitions and I left the install grub to /boot option on when I was installing Fedora. I would like to be able to add Windows 7 to the grub boot loader, but the advice I've seen online says to modify `/boot/grub/grub.conf`, but I don't have that file.

```
$ ls /boot/grub/
splash.xpm.gz
```

Has anyone done this? I'm thinking that I'll just need to re-install everything and use the Windows boot loader, but it would be nice to use grub instead.

Comment: you might meed to install os-prober package as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Connect Windows 7 Disk.
2. Boot with Fedora Disk.
3. Launch Terminal login root user.
4. `update-grub`
5. Restart.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `update-grub`? Is that a program? If so, when I try it I get `command not found`.

Comment: @kyle `update-grub` is a Ubuntu (and perhaps Debian) command for updating grub. You might want to try `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` to update grub.

Answer (score 3):

`grub.conf` is not in `/grub` but in `/boot/grub2`.